# Add environment variable in lambda function from serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

Hi there i am new in serverless framework i want to add environment variable into lambda function but condition is environment variable value will be different based on staging for Eg: is staging is dev then environment variable value will be "this is dev value" if environment variable is prod then value should be "this is prod value"

this is my .yml file

```
service: serverless-test2

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1


layers:
  commonLibs:
    path: layer
   
functions:
  new:
    handler: handler
    environment:
      password: "this is value of password in dev"
    layers:
        # Ref name is generated by TitleCasing the layer name & appending LambdaLayer
      - { Ref: CommonLibsLambdaLayer }
```

Here i want to change "password" environment variable value based on stage

can anyone help how do i set condition for it

something if else in environment variable

Answer (score 2):

Serverless Framework has built-in support for this exact case, please see how to use Stage Parameters, the example in docs refers exactly to setting an environment variable that differs between stages: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters#stage-parameters